# Previous business day in different time zone - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to obtain the previous business day in Europe (country: Netherlands).

I know that you can use the following function to obtain the previous business day in the US:

```
dy = busdate(floor(now), -1);
```

However, how do you add the locality into account?

A good example is 01/15/2018. The US market was closed whereas in Europe it was a regular business day.

Comment: the `busdate`-function has 4 inputs the third of which is "holidays". you can just download a list of all holidays in your country from somewhere (you might have to format it correctly) and pass it to the function.

Comment: Did you check `tzoffset` function?

Comment: @Max Yes I am doing that now. But Matlab does not control this?

Comment: @Hazem I have used tzoffset to switch between time zones. However, I don't see how to use it in this example.

Comment: @JohnAndrews maybe there is a way to do it, but at least I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you'll need to add a vector of your custom holidays `H` (retrieve from web or elsewhere):

```
dy = busdate(dateReference, -1, H);
```